# Whats the best way to compare large amounts of data between two different databases?

Tags: c#, data-integrity

I have one desktop application receiving data from a webservice and storing it inside a local postgresql database (while the webservice retrieves data from a SQL Server database). At the end of the process there will be a minimum of 2.5 million entries inside a table in my local database but this will be received from de webservice in batches of about 300 rows at time and within a time frame of about 15 days.

What I need is a way to make sure that my local database has the exact same information the server's database has.

I'm thinking of creating some sort of checksum for each batch received and then, after all batches were received, another checksum of the entire table but I don't know if this is the best solution and, if is, I don't know where to start to create it.

PS: TCP already handles integrity check so I don't even know if this is needed, but it is critical that the data are the same.

Comment: as ben suggests, a lot depends on whether you have control of the SQL Server database. Since you're using a web service to pull the data rather than extracting it using SQL Server admin tools, I assume you don't have control of the SQL Server side, but it would help for you to confirm that.

Comment: Well, while I do have control over both the web service and SQL Server, it's mandatory for me that I use the web service for data pulling (massive) and pushing (very little, at the the end of the process).

Comment: Two things I forgot to mention is that the tables in the SQL server  are way different in the postgresql server. Data is spread between many tables and databases on the SQL Server's side and just one single table containing just a small part of the data on the local postgresql database. And that there will be several instances of the desktop application running in diferent places pulling different rows from the web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see how a checksum could *possibly* be useful, but the amount of transformation you're doing would probably make it impractical. You'd have to derive the checksum on either the original form of the data or on the transformed form; it wouldn't be valid on both.

You have some strange constraints (been there myself), so it's kind of hard to come up with a clear strategy without knowing all the details. Maybe one of the following suggestions would work.

1. A simple count(*) on the SQL Server side and on the PostgreSQL side after the migration is complete.
2. Dump out a list of keys from the SQL Server side and from the PostgreSQL side after the migration is complete, and then sort and compare those files.
3. If 1 and 2 aren't possible because of limited access to SQL Server, maybe dump out the results of the web service calls to a single file location as you go along, and then extract the same data from PostgreSQL at the end, and compare those files.

There are numerous tools available for comparing files if you choose options 2 or 3.

Comment: Hmm... and what about creating the checksum from the web service's returning object (a **list<class>**)? This way I would create another object containing the list and the list's crc code and then return it so I can make the same checksum on the desktop app and compare them both. Would it work?

Comment: I'm not any kind of expert on checksums, but from what I've read they typically are applied on both sides of a transmission, to the entire body of data, which would typically be identical and in the same format. I don't know that you'd be able to calculate a checksum piecemeal across a bunch of clients and separate processes. Maybe you could, but the complexity of that operation might outweigh its usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the web service and SQL Server DB? If you do, SQL Server Change Tracking should do the trick. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322.aspx) Change Tracking will track every change (or just the changes you care about) on a per table basis. Each time you synchronize you just pass it your version number and it will return the changeset required to bring you up to date.

Comment: It would be great but I don't have this option. I must do it using the web service. Mainly because of the way the project was conceived but there's also the fact that the MS SQL Server *may* be replaced by an Oracle server in the future.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply removing the web service. I just meant you could expose the SQL Changing Tracking functionality in a web service. I've done this to replicate data to WinMo handheld computers. The main reason I suggested this is because handling updates and deletes can be difficult and Changing Track make that trivial. Still that will not work if the DB is migrated to Oracle.